# Improving performance of gurobi program

Tags: optimization, gurobi, quadratic-programming

I have $n$ points in an $n$-dimensional space (more specifically, the points are basis vectors with small random perturbations).
I want to embed the points into a smaller-dimensional space: i.e. for $d \le n$ I want to find a mapping $f\colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^d$ while preserving the following property.

For any three distinct points $x,y,z$, we know whether $x$ is closer to $y$ or to $z$, i.e. is $\|x - y\|$ greater or less than $\|x - z\|$.
For a selected set of triplets $(x_1, y_1, z_1), \ldots, (x_m, y_m, z_m)$ such that $\|x_i - y_i\| < \|x_i - z_i\|$ for all $i$, we want to preserve this property in the embedding, i.e. we must also have
$$
    \|f(x_i) - f(y_i)\| < \|f(x_i) - f(z_i)\|
$$

**My solution**, I wrote a quadratic program in Gurobi which finds such an embedding.

```
m = gp.Model()
# Variables: for each of n original point, we want to find a d-dimensional vector
vars = [m.addMVar(shape=dim) for i in range(n)]

# Constraint: x is closer to y than to z
for const in constraints:
    x, y, z = [vars[i] for i in const]
    m.addConstr((y - z) @ (2 * x - (y + z)) >= 1)
```

The above is true since
$$
\|f(x) - f(y)\|^2 < \|f(x) - f(z)\|^2
\iff \left\langle f(y) - f(z), f(x) - (f(y) + f(z)) / 2 \right\rangle > 0
$$
(Intuitively, we look at the hyperplane in the middle between $f(y)$ and $f(z)$. This hyperplane has the normal vector $f(y) - f(z)$ and goes through the point $(f(y) + f(z)) / 2$. I add $1$ ion the RHS to guarantees strong inequality)

I just want to find any embedding, so I set the objective to constant $0$ and run `m.optimize()`.

**Problem 1**: If I run it as is, I have problems with large numbers: for some reason, the model tends to consider very large numbers, even when there exist single-digit integer solutions. Sometimes it affects convergence. To counter this, I bound the numbers, either by norm:

```
for v in vars:
    m.addConstr(v @ v <= bound * bound)
```

or by coordinates:

```
for v in vars:
    m.addConstr(v <= bound)
    m.addConstr(v >= -bound)
```

Both approaches seem to perform the same.

**Question**: Is it a standard approach? My main issues are: 1) I don't know how to select the bound (I just try different values), 2) it feels weird that I need to do anything like this in the first place, 3) it introduces additional constraints, which also might affect performance.

**Problem 2**: The model doesn't converge even for moderately-sizes instances.
E.g. if I have $n=20$ points, even taking $d=n$ (so the solution is guaranteed to exist), I randomly select $100$ triplets, it doesn't converge within $10$ minutes (for this size,I want it to finish in seconds).

**Question**: Is there a way to improve the performance? My experience with Gurobi is 1 day, so there might be very simple tricks I'm not aware of. In particular, maybe there exists a way to rewrite the constraints to make the program faster?

The constraints must be satisfied.

Comment: Try this link: https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/12380867295633-Making-MIP-converge-faster. Particular, look at the parameter MIPfocus.

Comment: @SutanuMajumdar, thank you. I set `m.params.MIPFocus = 1`, doesn't seem to work

Comment: make it 3 & check once more please

Comment: @SutanuMajumdar, thank you. I experimented more, and this are the conclusions: 1) Changing the bound for variable norm from $10^5$ to $10^4$ helps (for the setting described above, the optimization finishes in ~4 seconds). 1) Setting MIPSFocus to 1 doesn't change things. Changing to 3 makes the time worse (~15 seconds IIRC)